# Displaying items from a php session shopping cart

Tags: php, cart

I am writing a shopping cart and so far have set up a session using this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
{
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
?>
```

The elements added to the cart are all keys to a database (image_id). I'm just wanting to display each individual image_id along with the option to remove it from the cart.

At the moment I have one function which displays the total number of elements

```
function writeShoppingCart() {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (!$cart) {
        return '<p>0</p>';
    } else {
        // Parse the cart session variable
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
        return '<p>'.count($items).'</p>';
    }
}
```

I'd just love some advice on how to show the actual image_id's

Many thanks

Comment: How does the cart-session variable look like? (print_r($_SESSION['cart']))

Comment: that prints out the id's.... so a series of numbers. I guess from that I need to find a way to separate them. Is that easy?

Comment: Can you please supply what numbers and how they are formatted? (update your question)

Comment: adding four items to the cart and using your code I get.... 2,2,6,65

Comment: Why are you exploding `$cart` which is already an array? Why define `$s` if you aren't going to use it?  Where do you set the id's into cart?  Do yo know how to use a `foreach()` loop?

Comment: Sorry mike, this code is leached from various online resources, I don't really know what you mean

Comment: "Sorry mike, this code is leached from various online resources, I don't really know what you mean " - forgive me for saying so, but "I am writing a shopping cart and so far have set up a session using this:" is kind of misleading.